# Power BI - Filtering does not work on a child column, when a particular DAX formula is used

Tags: powerbi, filtering, dax, relationship

Please see the attached power bi model excerpt: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D24cyDv3Y9k2fY6EgtWAERFgWoA9uGxC/view?usp=sharing

I have a formula that calculates which of the rows in the table is the latest value, given the 'To' value in the Date Slicer. If you move the 'To' date to a date in Jan 2021 or prior, the value 1 will be in a different row.

The formula works, but when I try to pull in the column value from the parent (Units table), the Table Visual shows all the units, even though I have filtered for a single unit. Even setting bi-directional relationship does not help.

Can someone explain why this behaviour occurs and how I can pull in Unit Code into the Table Visual that you see. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data - not a pbix file - and the calculation you have tried? Also, the desired output in tabular form could help.

Comment: @AngeloCanepa The attached file has the actual data, the relationships I am using, and the actual DAX formula (which may or may not be relevant to the solution). The desired output is that the number of rows should remain the same when I add 'Unit Code' to the Table Visual.

Comment: Please read the following guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

To display the `Unit Code` values where the `Is Latest Revision` is 1, you can create a measure with the DAX as follows:

```
    Measure = IF([Is Latest Revision] = 1, 'Unit Revision'[Unit Code], BLANK())
```

The measure is to check if the `Is Latest Revision` is 1 or not, if the value is 1 then DAX will return `Unit Code` otherwise, a blank value.

As a result, you will only get the value for rows where `Is Latest Revision` is 1.

[image: Output]

Comment: Actually, I was originally able to use a measure to get Unit Code, even for 'Is Latest Revision' = 0, but there are many columns in the Units table, and not only would this be inefficient, I am also looking to understand the root cause behind this behaviour. I also was able to adjust the ILR metric formula to return blank where the relationship was not proper, but am not able to understand what's wrong with the model setup.

Comment: I think what's happening here is that the measure `Unit Code` is taking every value from the column. Instead, it should look for only those values which satisfy the condition. You can try adding some conditional statements like `Filter` or `IF`. It should work in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting the desired values because the `Unit Code` measure is to look for all the values instead of a few particular ones.

To overcome this issue, you can add an `if` condition at the start.

```
    Unit Code =
    IF (
        [Is Latest Revision] = 1,
        LOOKUPVALUE (
                   Units[Unit Code],
                   Units[Id], SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Unit Revision'[Unit Id] )
         )
       )
```

This should give you the following output

[image: Output]

Comment: This solution is similar to the previously suggested solution, and earlier I did try using LOOKUPVALUE on Unit Code as a measure, and with all values of [Is Latest Revision], not just 1. I'd primarily like to understand why the number of rows blow up when I add a column from the parent table in combination with the [Is Latest Revision] measure, and also avoid having to pull [Unit Code] as a measure